# find recursively a JSON value

Tags: javascript, json

I've got an exception in chrome : "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

I'm trying to extract an JSON value named "menus" which contains submenus

See my [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/NP7P5/473/)

==JAVASCRIPT==

```js
gedControllers.factory('getmenu', function($timeout, $http) {
    var menu = {
        fetch: function() {
            return $timeout(function() {
                return $http.get('config.json').then(function(response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
            }, 3);
        }
    }

    return menu;
});

function isInArray(needle, haystack) {
    var foundNeedle = false;

    for (var key in haystack) {

        if (isInArray(needle, haystack[key])) {
            foundNeedle = true;
        }

        if (key == needle) {
            foundNeedle = true
        }
    }

    return foundNeedle;
}

gedControllers.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, getmenu) {
    getmenu.fetch().then(function(data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        $scope.menu = isInArray("menu",data);
        console.log($scope.menu);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

   
    <div ng-controller='AppCtrl'>
            <script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
                {{ category.label }}
                <ul ng-if="category.menus">
                    <li ng-repeat="category in category.menus" ng-include="'categoryTree'">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </script>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="category in menus" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

But the original json I to big [plunker link][2]

[2]: http://plnkr.co/edit/GSwlCl0y2j6HRABf98pd?p=preview"plunker link which bug"

How can I optimize my code ?

Comment: Where is the JSON involved here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just Javascript Objects. You are looking to do a deep search. Here's a way you could do it:

```js
function deepKeySearch(obj, key) {
  for (iKey in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(iKey)) {
      if (iKey === key) {
        return obj[iKey];
      } else if (typeof obj[iKey] === 'object' && obj[iKey] !== null) {
        var search = deepKeySearch(obj[iKey], key);
        if (search !== undefined) {
          return search;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var obj = {
  obj: {
    obj: {
      menu: 'Hey',
      arrTest: [0]
    }
  }
}

console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, 'menu') !== undefined); //does exist
console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, 'nonExistantKey') !== undefined); //doesn't exist
console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, 'arrTest') !== undefined); //does exist
```

Can be rewritten if you just want to check the existence of the key:

```js
function deepKeySearch(obj, key) {
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    return keys.some(function (iKey) {
        if (iKey === key) {
            return true;
        } else if (typeof obj[iKey] === 'object' && obj[iKey] !== null) {
            return deepKeySearch(obj[iKey], key);
        }
    });
}

var obj = {
    obj: {
        obj: {
            menu: 'Hey',
            arrTest: [0]
        }
    }
}

console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, 'menu')); //does exist
console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, 'nonExistantKey')); //doesn't exist
console.log(deepKeySearch(obj, '0')); //does exist
```

Comment: ok, your code works but  how can I get the tree view with your result ? It's a flattened array

Comment: @kakame94, no idea what you mean. If you want to find a property by name and get the value of that property then use the first function. The difference between the two functions, is that the first one will return the value associated with the key (or undefined if it doesn't find it) while the other one returns true or false depending on the existence of the property.

Comment: finally I JSON.stringify the multidimensional array and it works fine ;) thx

Answer (score 0):

If the json you're iterating over is your `config.json` from the plunker link, your iteration will take the following path:

1. `haystack` is entire object, first key is `results`
2. `haystack` is `haystack['results']`, first key is `myAdmin`
3. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']`, first key is `count`
4. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']['count']`. No keys, continue
5. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']['attributes']`, first key is `name`
6. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']['attributes']['name']`, first key is `0` (the value of the property is `"name"`, `Object.keys("name")` yields `["0","1","2","3"]` as characters in strings are accessible by index)
7. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']['attributes']['name']['0']`, first key is `0` (the value is now, `"n"`, also a string, `Object.keys("n")` is `["0"]`)
8. `haystack` is `haystack['results']['myAdmin']['attributes']['name']['0']['0']`, first key is `0`. This is where your start your path towards a stack overflow exception, since the haystack will always be `"n"` which will always have a property `"0"`.

You should make sure that `typeof haystack === 'object'` before you start iterating over its properties.